# Tortoise SVN how to completely remove/delete Repo

Tags: visual-studio, svn, tortoisesvn, visualsvn

I have installed Tortoise SVN and used it once or twice but I set it up incorrectly and would like to do a full wipe and reinstall. I do also have the Visual SVN plugin installed in Visual studio. This includes deleting any repositories that I have created. I tried deleting and reinstalling everything including my Repository, and reinstalling the Visual SVN, but now I cant create a new repository on visual SVN in the same location because it says that it already exists?

Comment: Try going to the folder and showing hidden files, there should be a .svn folder there. If you delete that, it should solve your issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Try going to the folder and showing hidden files, there should be a .svn folder there. If you delete that, it should solve your issue. – Nanos Apr 4 '18 at 17:44

@Nanos's Comment is what I was looking for.